# Add page number to PDF with Python, preserving hyperlink

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I have a PDF file with internal Hyperlink in it. I want to Python to add page number to each page and preserve the hyperlink in it. I tried PyPDF2, page number was added but the Hyperlink was gone.
Here is my code:

Here is my code with PyPDF2 3.0.0

```
import PyPDF2
from fpdf import FPDF

class NumberPDF(FPDF):
    def __init__(self, numberOfPages):
        super(NumberPDF, self).__init__()
        self.numberOfPages = numberOfPages

    # Overload Header
    def header(self):
        pass

    # Overload Footer
    def footer(self):
        # Do not print footer on first page 
        #if self.page_no() != 1:
            # Position at 1.3 cm from bottom
            self.set_y(-13)
            # Arial italic 8
            self.set_font('Arial', 'I', 8)
            # Page number
            #self.cell(0, 10, f"Page {self.page_no()-1} of {self.numberOfPages-1}", 0, 0, 'C')
            #self.cell(0, 10, f"Page {self.page_no()} of {self.numberOfPages}", 0, 0, 'C')
            self.cell(0, 10, f"{self.page_no()}", 0, 0, 'C')

def add_PN(pdf_file):
        
    infile = PyPDF2.PdfReader (pdf_file)
    total_pages=len(infile.pages)
    
    #get page orientation information for the merged file
    orientation=[]
    
    for i in range(total_pages):
        page = infile.pages[i].mediabox
        if (page.right - page.left) > (page.top - page.bottom):
            orientation.append('L')
        else:
            orientation.append('P')
    
    #Create temp PDF with page number
    tempNumFile = NumberPDF(total_pages)
    
    for i in range(total_pages):
        tempNumFile.add_page(orientation[i])
        
    # Save the temporary PDF with number
    tempNumFile.output(temp_folder + '\\' + "tempNumbering.pdf")
        
    # Create a new PDFFileReader for the temporary numbering PDF
    tempNumFile = PyPDF2.PdfReader(temp_folder + '\\' + "tempNumbering.pdf")        
    
     # Create a new PDFFileWriter for the final output document
    mergeWriter = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    
    # Loop through the pages in the temporary numbering PDF
    for x, page in enumerate(tempNumFile.pages):
        # Grab the corresponding page from the inputFile
        inputPage = infile.pages[x]
        # Merge the inputFile page and the temporary numbering page
        inputPage.merge_page(page)
        # Add the merged page to the final output writer
        mergeWriter.add_page(inputPage)
        
    # Write the merged output
    with open(pdf_file, 'wb') as fh:
        mergeWriter.write(fh)
```

Comment: @KJ Thanks for your reply. In my PDF file, I have links on page 2, I can click a link to jump to my designated page. On pages 3 to the end of the file, each page has a link, click it to jump back to page 2. It is not necessary to use merge_page to add page numbers. I tried to use reportlab to add page number on each page. But it failed to keep the link. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Thank you very  K J. Seems like there is no quick way to make it with Python. I will look around to see if there is other way. Thank you again !